# Using a4j:support to make PanelGrid clickable, after the click the page doesn't refresh

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces

I've made a button using HTMLPanelGrid and HTMLAjaxSupport (a4j:support from backing bean) that responds to 'onclick'.

The eventlistener registered with the  HTMLAjaxSupport  adds a component to the page (a different component with a different backing bean).

The problem is, the addition is not visible until I refresh the page or press another button that refreshes the display. I'm trying to figure out how to refresh the page.

To sum it up - I would like to know how to refresh a visual component backed up by a backing bean after the backing bean had changed. (The refresh should occur after clicking an ajax supported component)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

all `<a4j:` tags have the `reRender` attribute. It should point to the `id` of the object/area you want to refresh.

Note that if a component has been hidden, you must reRender its *parent*. For example:

```
<h:panelGroup id="newComponentWrapper">
<!-- your component goes here -->
</h:panelGroup>
...
<a4j:support reRender="newComponentWrapper" .. />
```

And another advice - avoid using the `binding` attribute - in 95% of the cases you can go without it.

Comment: Thanks!
About the binding attribute - How would you add and change components dynamically without it? (That's the main reason why I use binding currently)

Comment: just use `rendered="#{condition}` for a component, then change the condition and reRender